# How to rectify this problem

Tags: magento-1.9.3.3

```
Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
    at Function.observe (prototype.js:5653)
    at klass.initialize (validation.js:98)
    at new klass (prototype.js:101)
    at klass.initialize (form.js:35)
    at new klass (prototype.js:101)
    at home:649
observe @ prototype.js:5653
initialize @ validation.js:98
klass @ prototype.js:101
initialize @ form.js:35
klass @ prototype.js:101
(anonymous) @ home:649
prototype.js:5734 Uncaught TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function
    at fire (prototype.js:5734)
    at HTMLDocument._methodized [as fire] (prototype.js:438)
    at HTMLDocument.fireContentLoadedEvent (prototype.js:5820)
fire @ prototype.js:5734
_methodized @ prototype.js:438
fireContentLoadedEvent @ prototype.js:5820
```

Comment: I suggest to debug using browser's JavaScript debugger. Is this caused by an Ajax call or during page load ?

Answer (score 0):

On which screen you are getting this issue?
Please attach screenshot of front-end with error to understand it more clearly.

Are you using jquery.min.js and prototype on the same page? If so then this might be Jquery conflict issue.

After all the jQuery script tags add below line:

`<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you add an event handler to an element that does not exist. Please post your code and your debugging so far if you need more input.